# How to simulate sql join?

Tags: sql, join, nosql

Now I tried to use the sql join algorithms ([Nested loop join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join)) for simulating the operation that joining two (or more) tables in nosql.

If I have two tables TableA and TableB,now I want to join these. First I will SELECT all record(s) form these two tables.And using two loops to find record(s) from TableA and TableB that satisfy(s) the join condition.

But now I can't handle the join-on-condition like this:

```
(TableA.id = TableB.id OR TableA.name= TableB.name) AND TableA.age = TableB.age
```

Could I convert the complex join-on-condition which cantains '(' or ')' to one-level join-on-condition which only contains AND , OR.(Like this: TableA.id = TableB.id AND TableA.age = TableB.age OR TableA.name= TableB.name AND TableA.age = TableB.age )

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are large, you could join partitions of each table using playOrm.  If the tables are small, you could just use the join in playOrm.  I assume you are talking about nosql.  If the tables are very large, you will want to use map/reduce.  playOrm joins are more for OLTP applications that partition by account or partition by month or by client so you can have an infinite amount of clients and just query into the partitions of the client you are dealing with.